# How do I pay functions in remix?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-design, payable

I am making an NFT vending machine. Here's the code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^ 0.8.10;

contract VendingMachine {

    address payable internal vendingAdmin;

    struct item {
        string itemName;
        uint8 itemPrice;
        uint8 inventory;
        bool inStock;
    }
    
    item[] public Items;

    constructor() {
        payable(msg.sender) == vendingAdmin;
        Items.push(item("Dr. Pepper", 5, 1, true));
        Items.push(item("Pepsi", 5, 1, true));
        Items.push(item("Fiji Water", 10, 1, true));
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    function seeAvailableItems(uint8 index) public view returns (string memory, uint8, uint8, bool) {
        require(index < 3 , "There are only 3 items in this vending machine. Please enter an index between 0 and 2, inclusive.");
        item storage vendingItemInfo = Items[index];
        return (vendingItemInfo.itemName, vendingItemInfo.itemPrice, vendingItemInfo.inventory, vendingItemInfo.inStock);
    }

    function buyDrPepper() public payable {
        require(Items[0].inStock == true);
        require(msg.value == Items[0].itemPrice , "You have not paid enough for this item!");
        vendingAdmin.transfer(msg.value);
        // what do I actually send them?
        Items[0].inventory--;
        if (Items[0].inventory == 0) {
            Items[0].inStock == false;
        } 
    }

    function buyPepsi() public payable {
        require(Items[1].inStock == true);
        require(msg.value == Items[0].itemPrice , "You have not paid enough for this item!");
        vendingAdmin.transfer(msg.value);
        // what do I actually send them?
        Items[1].inventory--;
        if (Items[1].inventory == 0) {
            Items[1].inStock == false;
        } 
    }

    function buyFijiWater() public payable {
        require(Items[2].inStock == true);
        require(msg.value == Items[0].itemPrice , "You have not paid enough for this item!");
        vendingAdmin.transfer(msg.value);
        // what do I actually send them?
        Items[2].inventory--;
        if (Items[2].inventory == 0) {
            Items[2].inStock == false;
        } 
    }

}
```

I am deploying this contract in REMIX. It compiles and deploys, but I can't figure out how to use the buyDrPepper, buy Pepsi, or buyFijiWater functions after its deployed. I keep trying to pay but it keeps giving me the error "You have not paid enough for this item!"

Do I have to put all the logic in the receive fxn?

Answer (score 0):

Insert the amount you want to pay in the `Value` field in Remix. It is at the top, above the functions you're calling.

Comment: So I did try that. The issue is that the struct element itemPrice is stored as a uint, not as ether. So in the buy function, it's expecting a uint, not a price. If I change the second line of the buy fxns to say 5 ether instead of calling the array's index and struct, the function works.

Comment: A uint and a price are the same. It seems you are mismatching the units: in your constructor you are setting the prices in "wei", which is the minimal amount possible. 10^18 = 10^18 wei = 1 ether. When you write `Items.push(item("Dr. Pepper", 5, 1, true));` it is the same as setting the price to 5 wei. If you want it in ether, change the 5 to "5 ether".

Comment: Cool, that worked. Now could you tell me why my buy functions don't set the inStock bool to false after I buy? haha :D

Comment: You're using `==` (checks equality) instead of `=` (sets variable)

Comment: Kenzo youre a ninja bro